# Getting Firebase Functions Internal Error

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, razorpay

I am trying to implement Razorpay Payment Integration with Firebase Cloud Functions API in Android. Every is working fine but when verifying the payment on the server Firebase Functions Throw an Internal Error as FirebaseFunctionsEceptions.InternalError.

This is my server side code

```
exports.confirmPayment = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (context.auth) {
    const amount = data.amount;
    const text = data.razorpay_order_id + "|" + data.razorpay_payment_id;
    var signature = crypto
      .createHmac("sha256", key_secret)
      .update(text)
      .digest("hex");

    if (signature === data.razorpay_signature) {
      console.log("PAYMENT SUCCESSFUL");
      return { text: "PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL" };
    } else {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('Invalid Pack Bought', 'Your payment was unsuccessful due to invalid pack purchasing!')
    }
  }else{
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('Unauthenticated User', 'Unable to confirm Payment!')
  }
});
```

And my Android Studio Java Code is

When Payment Is Successful Razorpay's onPaymentSuccess is thrown and after the payment I have to verify if the payment made is authentic and has same amount. which is done by verifyPayment method which is given below

```
@Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s, PaymentData paymentData) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Payment Successful verifying now!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Task<String> results = verifyPayment(paymentData);
        results.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Snackbar.make(btnBuy.getRootView(), "Points have been added to your balance!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BuyPointsActivity.this, "" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Payment Verification Method is Called Via This Method

```
private Task<String> verifyPayment(PaymentData data) {
        Map<String, Object> data1 = new HashMap<>();
        data1.put("razorpay_payment_id", data.getPaymentId());
        data1.put("razorpay_order_id", data.getOrderId());
        data1.put("amount", amount);
        data1.put("razorpay_signature", data.getSignature());
        data1.put("push", true);
        return functions
                .getHttpsCallable("confirmPayment")
                .call(data1)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                        // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                        // propagated down.
                        String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                        return result;
                    }
                });
    }
```

This is the Cloud Functions Log

```
confirmPayment
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"mmbestonbest@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"47.30.174.168","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/8.0.1,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2020-04-05T03:49:42.041Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.update","granted":true,"resourceAttributes":{}}],"resourceName":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment","request":{"updateMask":"sourceUploadUrl,name,labels,runtime,httpsTrigger","@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.UpdateFunctionRequest","function":{"runtime":"nodejs8","name":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment","httpsTrigger":{},"labels":{"deployment-callable":"true","deployment-tool":"cli-firebase"},"sourceUploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-2535687d-781c-43d3-8bb1-6cdc1434531f/0cdb81e8-551c-4de7-83c0-8fe50f5a97bb.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-615941328944@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1586060376&Signature=rF3FqDJFIbAXSLK8DiemM6X%2BfTvMhv6RMpSvFCaHFjSfQ1kEf%2B5jV92LColV1k0szPt98HsExV2u2HGHRBSobobloyY8oAyh94WYHQTkVQZfhRGCOTvSliuhIhE98kRLVLOEPOjkyhNlz1v9kz48z1tq%2BRYyFB224joiU6qx4Qa58a08QZ3a1Ty4yQAuYedz2lgj3auKoJj10MzGf9T9YW3ffvN9vy4fF1z10erVaNMspgrZoU43NnJGWt%2B185ZRT9Gx%2B6mfxYinkXlfeVj3b8WOKwcYGbtN1FnFaUf8wGX3fAb%2B6FRB2n5ATIchyNHnr1F7E6sbdpmG5cCDZE1kbQ%3D%3D"}},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["us-central1"]}}
9:20:10.642 AM
confirmPayment
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"mmbestonbest@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment"}
9:21:23.540 AM
confirmPayment
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"mmbestonbest@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"47.30.174.168","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/8.0.1,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2020-04-05T03:51:23.614Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.update","granted":true,"resourceAttributes":{}}],"resourceName":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment","request":{"updateMask":"sourceUploadUrl,name,labels,runtime,httpsTrigger","@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.UpdateFunctionRequest","function":{"sourceUploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-2535687d-781c-43d3-8bb1-6cdc1434531f/87426444-4523-4584-a501-e219ac62e36e.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-615941328944@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1586060478&Signature=g2AJztAxLbvci2q7MDms1K7%2B466Z2RM6ALQmeBdH%2By7AA3hMAkdKSI7B3FzY8g1m%2BBuMlO8fkCWBSXcgHauxsOni%2FNW1LD7MZ%2FSUSkZ4npE%2FyVNRy0aitEzVSo6GaPmV9415KoFADyXHAxNakuD8JPZ4wl7qn%2FdcmQ8cZRJ%2BX%2BZ7w2xRw6BmG%2Fbnnmy8DCZe%2F%2Fw%2BIBhM4bpSOO8Ne8nMDa7qAfMzMXHHU8PDuIuIqdOmdIG0xF0itGsw3bhvAc530xWcJY%2F%2B7u%2FUjaszVikTV9igU33nUsqA5%2FzuNLmXrR9B42gn1ncCiwjnx8rlrcETmKkMrD6%2FABM5nYEQ%2Fvy%2BRw%3D%3D","runtime":"nodejs8","name":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment","httpsTrigger":{},"labels":{"deployment-tool":"cli-firebase","deployment-callable":"true"}}},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["us-central1"]}}
9:21:56.574 AM
confirmPayment
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"mmbestonbest@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment"}
11:45:07.349 AM
confirmPayment
 {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"mmbestonbest@gmail.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"47.30.162.219","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/8.0.1,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2020-04-05T06:15:07.712Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.update","granted":true,"resourceAttributes":{}}],"resourceName":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment","request":{"updateMask":"sourceUploadUrl,name,labels,runtime,httpsTrigger","@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.UpdateFunctionRequest","function":{"runtime":"nodejs8","name":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment","httpsTrigger":{},"labels":{"deployment-callable":"true","deployment-tool":"cli-firebase"},"sourceUploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-2535687d-781c-43d3-8bb1-6cdc1434531f/82b41c31-8b5c-4cd4-857c-301b4f554dd5.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-615941328944@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1586069101&Signature=FNLT8XrMwerp00RaqJXMPj6qk7Ztawx0NSAYJIWnWsMy0xdvB0bgqUrYx0dUYGx38r1c6xtyN7mSqFEXEN4IDOkDqWCRFDibiABDmTG9J60F2822bCeReGyYvmTJGVA%2BvBELdtvoiSBaVFHHYQfQdCKGKObboW2950zEeuq52pk30M3doDCUoXuGQUDSpQrZnlXLabH6JjvPDDj6VYcF42HnUmnesd43yErky6ZiW2qo6F4nGAj9hwEDAKFJHX%2FoW1HLDdMjQ2EI0t9%2FPRBi6fvtNjLqbAtE7xjQSwvDlyU1uMFAqwVC5RxKeTGM195E6RbKlSY6YsEzp4rAWltU%2Fw%3D%3D"}},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["us-central1"]}}
11:45:32.142 AM
confirmPayment
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"mmbestonbest@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/beingfit-6c699/locations/us-central1/functions/confirmPayment"}
Logs are subject to Cloud Logging's
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you saw in the functions log.  We need to be able to see if the function actually did what you expected.

Comment: Sorry missed the log. I have updated the question with the log.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that payment was successful.  I think you need more logging to figure out what actually happened during the function execution. Every code path should log something to trace its behavior.

Comment: Actually I have tried to run a single method named addPoints with just a push to the database but still I am having the same Internal Error